# Change tenant logo on a specific site collection (O365_MainLink_TenantLogo)

Tags: office-365, spfx, spfx-extensions, site-logo, tenant

I know that changing top nav suite is bad practise, but I got a client that want to make a generic domain from a site collection (B2B)-> change tenant logo.

I don't know any solution to change the logo for only one site collection.

The only solution I guess is to make an SPFx extension, because I don't want that logo blinking when the DOM is ready.

Im also kind of new to spfx extension so any tips / help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not support changing anything in the suite nav bar. The DOM frequently changes in that space and your solution will break over time.

Comment: I know but in this case I probably have to use the same tenant because off all the integration and federated users.

Comment: That doesn't change the supportability -- it's not supported to change it.